# How to add an IE8 css hack to this PHP array?

Tags: php, css

I need to update some pre-existing codes.

```
css => array(
    'body' => 'overflow-x:hidden;',
    '#wrapper' => 'width:500px;'
)
```

I assume the `=>` suggests that its done in the PHP format.

What I need to do is add a IE8 css hack, I tried this but to no avail:

```
css => array(
    'body' => 'overflow-x:hidden;',
    '#wrapper' => 'width:500px;',
    '<!--[if IE 8]>#rightcol' => 'width:200px;<![endif]-->'
)
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville So `css` should be `$css`, right?

Comment: are you using vanilla php or are you using some sort of framework?

Comment: I'm presuming this is a framework you're working in? If so, can you let us know which one? We have no idea how this array is being used. Also, you seem to be missing a comma after `'#wrapper' => 'width:500px;'` in your second sample array.

Comment: @BenD No we're not using a framework... if we are I'm not sure what it is tbh. Thanks for pointing out the comman, I've added that in.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML change your opening body tag from `<body>`, to:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><body class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if ! IE 8]<!--><body><!--<![endif]-->
```

Then you can put `.ie8` before any css selector to make it work in only ie8:

```
css => array(
    'body' => 'overflow-x:hidden;',
    '#wrapper' => 'width:500px;',
    '.ie8 #rightcol' => 'width:200px;'
)
```

Comment: Are you Paul Irish, actually?

Answer (score 0):

This array is most probably injected (in a good sense) into your css code. If you know (by looking at the source code of your **loaded** php page) that this is the case, the HTML comments there won't work for you because it will try to write these in the css section, which is not valid.

You will need to make it rewrite a duplicate css for that IE8 condition. So you will have:

```
<style type="text/css">
/* this part is filled by your array values */
</style>

<!--[if IE 8]-->
<style type="text/css">
/* this part is the IE8 hack */
</style>
<!--[endif]-->
```

which will require and contain another **style** tag.

Comment: This would be easiest solution but I want to avoid this for now.

Comment: @muudless You can not add the hacks using HTML comments in CSS section no matter what because by default CSS code only accepts `/*…*/` syntax for the comments. So your best option seems to be to add an extra class to the selector that will need that hack, although I'm not sure if that will solve your issue.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Is there a way to do it with jquery in the format specified in my original question then?

Comment: Like Paul suggested you can write your additional rules (as hacks) in your array with something like **.ie8** -without the comments-. Then you can make use of specific jQuery selectors to add that class to necessary elements, ideally first by detecting the browser by JS and then taking this action accordingly. Otherwise if you have the option, echo/print that HTML comment, create a second css array (in PHP), make it add a new style tag and then close the HTML comment.